# Detecting UITouches while UIViewController is being shown as 3DTouch preview

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

Is it possible to detect touches and get the location of a touch from a `UIViewController` which is being currently used as `previewingContext` view controller for 3D Touch? (I want to change the image of within the preview controller when the touch moves from left to right)

I've tried both `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` none of them are fired.

```
class ThreeDTouchPreviewController: UIViewController {

func getLocationFromTouch(touches: Set<UITouch>) -> CGPoint?{
        guard let touch  = touches.first else { return nil }
        return touch.location(in: self.view)
    }
    //Not fired
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let location = getLocationFromTouch(touches: touches)
        print("LOCATION", location)
    }
    //Not fired
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = getLocationFromTouch(touches: touches)
        print("LOCATION", location)
    }
}
```

Even tried adding a UIPanGesture.

Attempting to replicate FaceBook's 3D Touch feature where a user can move finger from left to right to change the current image being displayed.
Video for context: https://streamable.com/ilnln

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to achive result same as in FaceBook's 3D Touch feature you need to create your own `3D Touch gesture class`

```
    import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class ForceTouchGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    var forceValue: CGFloat = 0
    var isForceTouch: Bool = false

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        handleForceWithTouches(touches: touches)
        state = .began
        self.isForceTouch = false
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        handleForceWithTouches(touches: touches)
        if self.forceValue > 6.0 {
            state = .changed
            self.isForceTouch = true
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        state = .ended
        handleForceWithTouches(touches: touches)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        state = .cancelled
        handleForceWithTouches(touches: touches)
    }

    func handleForceWithTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        if touches.count != 1 {
            state = .failed
            return
        }

        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            state = .failed
            return
        }
        forceValue = touch.force
    }
}
```

and now you can add this gesture in your `ViewController` in `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let gesture = ForceTouchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imagePressed(sender:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

Now you can manage your controller UI in Storyboard. Add `cover view` above `UICollectionView` and `UIImageView` in a center and connect it with `IBOutlets` in code.

Now you can add handler methods for gesture

func imagePressed(sender: ForceTouchGestureRecognizer) {

```
let location = sender.location(in: self.view)

guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(
    at: location) else { return }
```

let image = self.images[indexPath.row]

```
switch sender.state {
case .changed:
    if sender.isForceTouch {
        self.coverView?.isHidden = false
        self.selectedImageView?.isHidden = false
        self.selectedImageView?.image = image
    }

case .ended:
    print("force: \(sender.forceValue)")
    if sender.isForceTouch {
        self.coverView?.isHidden = true
        self.selectedImageView?.isHidden = true
        self.selectedImageView?.image = nil
    } else {
        //TODO: handle selecting items of UICollectionView here,
        //you can refer to this SO question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372609/collectionview-didnt-call-didselectitematindexpath-when-superview-has-gesture
        print("Did select row at indexPath: \(indexPath)")
        self.collectionView?.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
    }

default: break
}
```

}

From this point you need to customize your view to make it look in same way as Facebook do.

Also I created small example project on GitHub https://github.com/ChernyshenkoTaras/3DTouchExample to demonstrate it

Comment: Just tested this out, great idea but doesn't work well with `UICollectionView`, it disables scrolling and tap actions

Comment: You are right. I've answer and fixed code on GitHub. Now scrolling is fixed, but you need to handle collectionView items selecting in `imagePressed:` function